# Replace zero elements in rows of a csr_matrix with entries from a vector

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse.csr_matrix M and a vector V of following dimensions.

```
M: 0.15M x 1.3M
V: 0.15M
```

I want to replace all 0 elements in rows of M with the corresponding entry in V.

```
M = [[0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 0],
     [6, 0, 8]]
V = [[11],
     [22],
     [33]]
```

I want to modify M to M' such that

```
M = [[11,  1,  2],
     [ 3,  4, 22],
     [ 6, 33,  8]]
```

This can easily be done in loops, but I am wondering if there are more elegant Pythonian ways. As my data are huge, I am looking for a very fast way to accomplish this task.

The loop version will look like:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        if M[i,j] == 0 and V[i] !=0:
            M[i,j] = V[i]
```

Comment: How typical is your example?  Do you know that each row has exactly one zero, so the number of zeros exactly matches number of elements in V?

Comment: "This can easily be done in loops..."  Please include this code, so anyone who provides an answer can be sure it does the same thing that your code does.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser No, I do not know that. I have included the loop version of what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that should be fast, and work without making `M` dense.  The result though will be dense.  There's no way around that

Expand `V` into a matrix of the same size as `M`

```
In [711]: Z = np.repeat(V,M.shape[1],axis=1)

In [712]: idx=M.nonzero()   

In [713]: Z[idx]=M.data

In [714]: Z
Out[714]: 
array([[11,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4, 22],
       [ 6, 33,  8]])
```

It finds where all the nonzero values of `M` are located (basically the `row` and `col` attributes of `M.tocoo()`. And then just replaces the `fill` values in `Z` with the corresponding `data` values from `M`.

This would fail in the case where `M` hasn't been pruned; where some elements have been set to zero.  That's because the full code for `M.nonzero` is:

```
    A = self.tocoo()
    nz_mask = A.data != 0
    return (A.row[nz_mask],A.col[nz_mask])
```

It might be safer to use

```
In [717]: Mc=M.tocoo()

In [718]: Z[Mc.row, Mc.col] = Mc.data

In [719]: Z
Out[719]: 
array([[11,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4, 22],
       [ 6, 33,  8]])
```

That would protect against possible reordering of `data` when converting from `csr` to `coo`.